# SQL Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. Trying to reset password

Tags: sql

I'm trying to reset a password and I keep on running into this error, which I don't see how it applied here.

```
UPDATE [Servicename].[dbo].[Password] 
SET salt = 'zfkI0NkJiIJR8Rubuuf800cxjp7epM7EjYkQIfzUxI=',
hash = '96u76IApmLmLzatzGnvFzPq2h4noZZCpc+GATM2VUxk=' 
WHERE userid = 'admin'`
```

Comment: Can you show the table definition for `[Servicename].[dbo].[Password]`?

Comment: Sounds like the field is a UniqueIdentifier - you need to provide a value that is a valid UUID (this value looks like it is not). Info: [uniqueidentifier-TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) Or in other words, UUIDs and encrypted strings/hashes are not really the same thing.